# How to install pyfft on python3x?

Tags: pip, python-3.4, pyfftw

I tried installing `pyfft` using `python -m pip install pyfft` and I get

```
Downloading/unpacking pyfft
  Downloading pyfft-0.3.8.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_echeverl/pyfft/setup.py) egg_info for package pyfft
    Python >=2.5 is required to use this module.
  Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Python >=2.5 is required to use this module.
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
```

I'm using Python 3.4.1

Answer (score 2):

From the [`pyfft` PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfft):

> **THIS MODULE IS DEPRECATED**. Its functionality has been moved to [Reikna](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reikna). The last version, 0.3.8, will remain on PyPi for backward compatibility purposes.

Reikna supports both Python 2 and Python 3. I suggest you install it instead.